# Got an error on mysql database backup time

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I have mysql database (mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1) on my host server. I want to take backup using SSH. So I login by root user and go to mysql and write the command as below

```
mysql> mysqldump -u username -p password --opt  dbname > filename.sql;
```

but this didnot work for me and gave me and error like

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump --u username -p password --opt  dbname > filename.sql;' at line 1
```

Can any one provide me a solution to me to make a backup.

I am making a backup on server directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to execute `mysqldump` from the `mysql` CLI.

```
mysql> mysqldump ...
^^^^^^
```

First exit `mysql`

```
mysql> exit
Bye
username$
```

and then in the command prompt start `mysqldump` on its own

```
$ mysqldump -uusername -p"password" --opt  dbname > filename.sql;
```

Comment: I just tried by exit from MySQL and put the backup command but I got a new error like " -bash: !JW8.: event not found".

Comment: @GhostAnswer First of all that means that your question is answered :). Now these characters I guess are part of your password? If your password contains characters other than alpanumeric ones you have to put your password in double quotes and place it right after `-p` **(no spaces)**. See updated answer.

Comment: I will check and tell you.